# Rails 3.0.2 Array#join HTML Safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails gem that uses a snippet like:

```
components = []
components << label_for(attribute)
components << ...
components << text_field(attribute)
return components.join
```

The gem worked fine in Rails 3.0.1, however it escapes (renders as text in a browser) all HTML after updating to Rails 3.0.2. What am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @sj26 points out, either use the rails built-in helper:

```
<%= safe_join(components) %>
```

Or use my [`rails_join`](https://github.com/marcandre/rails_join) gem to make `Array#join` html-safe aware, in which case your original code will work as is.

Comment: nb safe_join was added in rails 3.1

Answer (score 9):

`String#join` isn't `SafeBuffer`-aware.

`String#html_safe` marks that you string is already HTML-escaped, preventing users sneaking bits of HTML into your pages. Check out [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) by Yehuda Katz on `SafeBuffer` and why/how you should be using them.

If you have an array of `String` and `SafeBuffer` you want to concatenate, make sure you've run `#html_safe` on them all, or `#concat` them into a `SafeBuffer` like so:

```
['<one>', '<p>two</p>'.html_safe].inject ''.html_safe, &:concat
=> "&lt;one&gt;<p>two</p>"
```

Rails has a built-in helper called [`safe_join`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join) which will do this for you.

Comment: This is the better answer in my opinion. Join seems to be inherently unsafe. Just a question on the ''.html_safe. Is that just in case the first string in the array hasn't been marked as html_safe? Also, what's the difference between &:concat and :concat, the latter seems to work the same for me :)

Comment: The more correct answer is now to use [`safe_join(array)`][http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join] which is `Array#join` that understands `SafeBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

http://makandra.com/notes/954-don-t-mix-array-join-and-string-html_safe

```
class Array
  def html_safe_join(delimiter='')
    ''.html_safe.tap do |str|
      each_with_index do |element, i|
        str << delimiter if i > 0
        str << element
      end
    end
  end
end
[safe_string, unsafe_string].html_safe_join(' ') 
# '<span>foo</span>&lt;span&t;bar&lt;/span&gt;'
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are automatically HTML-escaped in Rails3. You need to change that last line to:

```
return components.join.html_safe
```

alternately, if editing the gem is too much hassle you can do it from the view:

```
<%= helper_name.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had no issues in Rails 3.0.1 with `join` (using the newer HTML-escape). Any reason why it specifically fails in Rails 3.0.2? Thanks.

Comment: I've created a super simple app to test your problem and found that 3.0.1 behaves for me as you're saying 3.0.2 does. Both escape the html unless I tell it not to (I did so useing the "raw" method in my helper)

Comment: Thanks JW and Adam. I just did a test and you are correct. I'm not sure why my gem was working for the last half-dozen versions, but this does fix my issue. Cheers!

Comment: Be aware this could allow XSS if you don't explicitly escape every piece of user-generated content in your array first.

Comment: As pointed by @sj26 and solution proposed by @marc-andre-lafortune the rails helper `safe_join` is a better way to go as it avoid XSS vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

how about manual quoting?

```
<%= raw ['<div>', 'any', '</div>'].map{|val| h(val)}.join('<br />') %>
```